# Load to google maps the markers in current viewport flask query url

Tags: google-maps, url, flask

I am building a google maps web app that contains thousands of markers. When dealing with a high number of markers it is important to only load the markers in the current viewport to not slow down the app. I want to make an AJAX call everytime the bounds changes and load the markers in the viewport. To determine what the viewport is I have to pass the northeast and southwest latitude and longitude coordinates as URL parameters to my backend, then I  have to query the SQL for the markers that are within the coordinates and place them in the map.

The issue is that I don't know how to send the coordinates from the front-end to the back-end without having to click a "submit" button.

This Is what I have so far:

Front-end:

```
      <div id="info" action="{{ url_for('data') }}">
        <p>NorthEast=</p>
        <p id="NElat" name ="NElat"></p>
        <p id="NElng" name = "NElng"></p>
        </br>
        <p>SouthWest=</p>
        <p id="SWlat" name ="SWlat"></p>
        <p id="SWlng" name ="SWlng"></p>
      </div>

        var bounds = map.getBounds();
    var NE = bounds.getNorthEast();
    var SW = bounds.getSouthWest();

    var neLat = NE.lat()
    var neLng = NE.lng()
    var swLat = SW.lat()
    var swLng = SW.lng()

    document.getElementById("NElat").innerHTML=neLat; 
    document.getElementById("NElng").innerHTML=neLng;
    document.getElementById("SWlat").innerHTML=swLat;
    document.getElementById("SWlng").innerHTML=swLng;

    downloadUrl('/data?neLat=' + neLat + "&neLng=" + neLng + "&swLat=" + swLat + "&swLng=" + swLng, function(results) {...}
```

Back-end:

```
 @app.route("/data")
def data():
    conn = e.connect()
    latt = request.args.get("neLat", "neLat")
    query = conn.execute("SELECT * FROM coordinates WHERE lat > ?", [latt])
    result = {'data': [dict(zip(tuple (query.keys()) ,i)) for i in query.cursor]}
    jsonData = json.dumps(result)
    return jsonData
```

Comment: How about using Javascript to create an event listener on the map for clicks?  When it detects a click, it could send an AJAX request to your backend to fetch the new markers.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I was specifically looking for a way to query the markers that are in the map viewport.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I just had to query all the request arguments for it to work
Back-end:

```
@app.route("/data", methods=["GET"])
def data():
    conn = e.connect()
    nelat = request.args["neLat"]
    nelng = request.args["neLng"]
    swlat = request.args["swLat"]
    swlng = request.args["swLng"]
    query = conn.execute("SELECT * FROM coordinates WHERE lat < ? AND lat > ? AND lng < ? AND lng > ?", [nelat, nelng, swlat, swlng])
    result = {'data': [dict(zip(tuple (query.keys()) ,i)) for i in query.cursor]}
    jsonData = json.dumps(result)
    return jsonData
```